# WordPress with Tor Onion Service (dual .com & .onion domains for same website)

Tags: multisite, routing

I'd like to make my existing wordpress website `www.example.com` also accessible over a tor onion service = `www.examplesite12345.onion`. How can I do this?

Note that the two domain's content should be identical, except that I don't want wordpress to be injecting the wrong domain into my content (of course, all my content won't specify the domain either).

I'm using wordpress multisite. I setup tor to point to my web server, but wordpress doesn't recognize the domain (not surprising). So wordpress simply returns with a `302` redirect to `http://www.example.com/wp-signup.php?new=www.examplesite12345.onion`

How do I tell wordpress that `www.examplesite12345.onion` isn't a new site, but just an alias for the existing site `www.example.com`? Obviously, a mere redirect from the `.onion` to the clearnet domain is not a valid answer.

Comment: Allowing WP to handle a `.onion` domain is the same as making it also handle multiple other TLD's. Routing traffic from the Tor network to WP itself though is not a WP problem though as it's an Nginx/Apache issue that would be the same for any PHP based CMS. What you're wanting is sometimes referred to as ***domain mapping***

Comment: @TomJNowell from what I can tell, wordpress domain mapping only applies to mapping one domain to a single site (and multiple domains to distinct sites). How can I map multiple domains to the same site using ***doman mapping*** without a redirect? https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/

Comment: WP will happily have its URL changed to any domain regardless of how the multisite was set up, but for it to handle multiple domains on the same site the only way I've seen is with a domain mapping plugin such as Mercator or WP Domain Mapping. Note I'm not referring to redirects, that article doesn't refer to mapping multiple domains on to the same site because that's not possible out of the box without additional plugins or code

Comment: I also tried editing the `wp_domain_mapping` table directly, but to no avail. Is there a way this can be setup just by editing the database to define additional domain(s) that point to the `blog_id`? Can you please point me to the documentation that describes how this `wp_domain_mapping` table works?

Comment: WP doesn't have a domain mapping table, you'll need to ask the support route for https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ plugin as 3rd party dev plugin dev support is offtopic hhere. Although you can do it via the network admin UI, I've never heard of anybody modifying database tables to get this working, direct table manipulation is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `.onion` alias for your existing wordpress site on the clearnet using the [Mercator wordpress plugin](https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator/releases).

While the Mercator plugin alone is sufficient to make your wordpress site accessible on a `.onion` (as an alias, so in addition to its clearnet site), you're going to want to make some changes to your wordpress child theme and web server config. Otherwise, you may experience issues such as:

1. A user visits your `.onion` site, but your wordpress theme has them load javascript from the clearnet site, defeating the security benefits of using the `.onion` in the first-place
2. A user visits your `.onion` site, but the first click they make on your site brings them back to the clearnet domain for the rest of their session, also defeating the purpose
3. Your wordpress theme or plugins stubbornly try to redirect the user to your `.onion` on https, which doesn't work because your cert isn't valid for a `.onion` domain.
4. A user visits your clearnet site using the Tor Browser, and never realizes that a more secure `.onion` version of your site is available

### rewrites

The first three issues can be solved by [updating your `wp-config.php` and/or your wordpress child theme(s) to do a regex substitute of your https clearnet domain with your http `.onion` domain](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2021/02/12/wordpress-multisite-tor-alias/), where necessary

### Onion-Location

The last issue can be solved by updating your web server config to [include the `Onion-Location` header](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/onion-location/)